# Why is base64 encoded PHP not being decoded?

Tags: php, magento, base64

I am running Magento ver. 1.6.2.0 on an Ubuntu EC2 instance but my forms return as base64 encoded php files, which are not being decoded.  Any ideas about turning on base64 decoding for Magento or PHP in general?

We have a contact us form that you can fill out and click submit.  This form came with the Magento theme we installed (CrispAndClean by Themeforest).  However, when you click submit, instead of the form being submitted, you are returned to a blank page. If you click view source you can see the base64 encoded PHP.

You can decode it using this site:
http://www.tareeinternet.com/scripts/decrypt.php

Here is the result:

?>http://www.facebook.com/rebimol * * * @author       Vladimir Popov * @copyright     Copyright (c) 2011 Vladimir Popov * @license        http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0) */class VladimirPopov_WebForms_Block_Webforms extends Mage_Core_Block_Template{ protected function _toHtml()    {       if((float)substr(Mage::getVersion(),0,3) <= 1.3){           if($this->getTemplate() == 'webforms/default.phtml' && $this->getData('nolegacy')!='0'){                $this->setTemplate('webforms/legacy.phtml');            }       }       $note = "Powered by WebForms

";      return parent::_toHtml().$note; }       public function getFormData(){      $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();       if(isset($data['id'])){         $data['webform_id'] = $data['id'];      }       if($this->getData('webform_id')){           $data['webform_id'] = $this->getData('webform_id');     }       return $data;   }       protected function _prepareLayout() {       if((float)substr(Mage::getVersion(),0,3)<=1.4)          error_reporting(E_ERROR);       $show_success = false;      $data = $this->getFormData();       //get form data     $webform = Mage::getModel('webforms/webforms')->load($data['webform_id']);      if(!Mage::registry('webform')) Mage::register('webform',$webform);              if(intval($this->getData('results')) == 1)          $this->getResults();                if($webform->getSurvey()){          $collection = Mage::getModel('webforms/results')->getCollection();                      if(Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn())              $collection->addFilter('webform_id',$data['webform_id'])->addFilter('customer_id',Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId());         else{               $session_validator = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getData('_session_validator_data');                $collection->addFilter('customer_ip',ip2long($session_validator['remote_addr']));           }           $count = $collection->count();          if($count>0){               $show_success = true;           }       }               if(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getWebformsSuccess() == $data['webform_id'] || $show_success){           Mage::register('show_success',true);            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setWebformsSuccess();       }               if($webform->getRegisteredOnly() && !Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()){           Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl($this->getRequest()->getRequestUri());         Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl(),301);     }               Mage::register('fields_to_fieldsets',$webform->getFieldsToFieldsets());             //use captcha       if(!Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()){            $pubKey = Mage::getStoreConfig('webforms/captcha/public_key');          $privKey = Mage::getStoreConfig('webforms/captcha/private_key');            if($this->captchaAvailable())               Mage::register('use_captcha',true);     }               //proccess the result       if($this->getRequest()->getParam('submitWebform_'.$data['webform_id'])){            //validate captcha          if(Mage::registry('use_captcha')){              if($this->getRequest()->getParam('recaptcha_response_field')) {                 $verify = $this->getCaptcha()->verify($this->getRequest()->getParam('recaptcha_challenge_field'),$this->getRequest()->getParam('recaptcha_response_field'));                    if($verify->isValid()){                     $success = $this->saveResult();                 } else {                        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($this->__('Verification code was not correct. Please try again.'));                        Mage::register('captcha_invalid',true);                 }               } else {                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($this->__('Verification code was not correct. Please try again.'));                    Mage::register('captcha_invalid',true);             }           } else {                $success = $this->saveResult();         }           if($success){               Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setWebformsSuccess($data['webform_id']);            }           //redirect after successful submission          $url = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();           if($webform->getRedirectUrl()){             if(strstr($webform->getRedirectUrl(),'://'))                        $url = $webform->getRedirectUrl();              else                    $url = $this->getUrl($webform->getRedirectUrl());           }           if($success)                Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);        }       parent::_prepareLayout();       $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle(Mage::registry('webform')->getName());           }       public function captchaAvailable(){     if(class_exists('Zend_Service_ReCaptcha')           && Mage::getStoreConfig('webforms/captcha/public_key')          && Mage::getStoreConfig('webforms/captcha/private_key')     ) return true;      return false;   }       public function getCaptcha(){       $pubKey = Mage::getStoreConfig('webforms/captcha/public_key');      $privKey = Mage::getStoreConfig('webforms/captcha/private_key');        if($pubKey && $privKey)         $recaptcha = new Zend_Service_ReCaptcha($pubKey, $privKey);     return $recaptcha;  }       public function saveResult(){       if(!Mage::registry('webform')) return false;        try{            $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();         $result = Mage::getModel('webforms/results');                       $session_validator = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getData('_session_validator_data');            $iplong = ip2long($session_validator['remote_addr']);           if((float)substr(Mage::getVersion(),0,3)<=1){               $iplong = ip2long($this->getRealIp());          }           $result->setData($postData)             ->setWebformId(Mage::registry('webform')->getId())              ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())              ->setCustomerId(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId())                ->setCustomerIp($iplong)                ->save();                           Mage::dispatchEvent('webforms_result_submit',array('result'=>$result,'webform'=>Mage::registry('webform')));                        $emailSettings = Mage::registry('webform')->getEmailSettings();                     if($emailSettings['email_enable']){                             $result = Mage::getModel('webforms/results')->load($result->getId());               $result->sendEmail();               if(Mage::registry('webform')->getDuplicateEmail()){                 $result->sendEmail('customer');             }           }           return true;        } catch (Exception $e){         Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($e->getMessage());         return false;       }   }       public function getRealIp() {        $ip = false;        if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))      {            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];      }       if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))        {            $ips = explode(", ", $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);             if($ip)             {                array_unshift($ips, $ip);                   $ip = false;           }           for($i = 0; $i < count($ips); $i++)             {                if(!preg_match("/^(10|172\.16|192\.168)\./i", $ips[$i]))                {                        if(version_compare(phpversion(), "5.0.0", ">="))                        {                            if(ip2long($ips[$i]) != false)                          {                                $ip = $ips[$i];                                 break;                             }                      }                       else                        {                            if(ip2long($ips[$i]) != - 1)                            {                                $ip = $ips[$i];                                 break;                             }                      }                  }              }      }       return ($ip ? $ip : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);  }       public function getResults(){       $data = $this->getData();               $webform = Mage::registry('webform');               //get results       $page_size = $data["page_size"];        $current_page = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('p');        if(!$current_page) $current_page = 1;       $from = $current_page*$page_size;       $results = Mage::getModel('webforms/results')->getCollection()          ->addFilter('webform_id',$webform->getId())         ->addFilter('approved',1)           ->setPageSize($page_size)           ->setCurPage($current_page)         ;       $results->getSelect()->order('created_time desc');              $last_page = $results->getLastPageNumber();             $page_url = $this->getUrl(Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getData('identifier'));       echo get_class($page_url);      if($current_page1){            $next_url= $page_url."?p=".($current_page-1);       }               Mage::register('prev_url',$prev_url);       Mage::register('next_url',$next_url);       Mage::register('current_page',$current_page);       Mage::register('results',$results);         }       protected function _afterToHtml($html){     Mage::unregister('webform');        Mage::unregister('fields_to_fieldsets');        Mage::unregister('prev_url');       Mage::unregister('next_url');       Mage::unregister('current_page');       Mage::unregister('results');        Mage::unregister('redirect_url');       Mage::unregister('use_captcha');        Mage::unregister('captcha_invalid');        return parent::_afterToHtml($html); }}?>

Comment: I'm a pretty experience PHP and Magento developer, but I don't know if I follow what you're talking about.  Examples might help.

Comment: Thanks for having a look; updated with specific example.

Comment: Is more information needed? What's wrong with this question?

Answer (score 0):

Part of the answer seems to be that the eval command in the first part of the page that is returned is not being executed:

eval(gzinflate(str_rot13(base64_decode('HZrHkoNLtlJ/pXRdFQwA4aNaBd57z6QDYoX3X/9HLwc5yQiBuOfsvZZFf/3333/9ozzT4Y